# How to find table name using select query

Tags: mysql, vb.net

```
SELECT product FROM Table_name_1 
WHERE id = '% textbox1.text %'  
UNION  
SELECT product FROM Table_name_2 
WHERE id = '% textbox1.text %'  
UNION  
SELECT product FROM Table_name_3
WHERE id = '% textbox1.text %'
```

Through this code, I am able to get the products. But how will I know from which table this result fetch out? So I want to know table name too.

Comment: You could just include an extra hard-coded column of table name in each select...

Comment: Thanks ....but i want to know that any sql query is there or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also select constant values and give them a column name.

```
SELECT product, 'Table_name_1' as table FROM Table_name_1 WHERE id = '% textbox1.text %'
UNION
SELECT product, 'Table_name_2' as table FROM Table_name_2 WHERE id = '% textbox1.text %' 
UNION
SELECT product, 'Table_name_3' as table FROM Table_name_3 WHERE id = '% textbox1.text %'
```

Comment: Then how I will fetch table name....  dim table_name as string = rs.getString()....

Comment: You will fetch the table name just like you fetch the product. If that's not what you want please clarify.